# What is new functionality 'Sparks' that appears in the Flash Builder 4?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder, flex-spark

i just checking Flash Builder 4 ( i come from Flex builder 3 ), and it was painfull to see that old CSS visual editor, that it was very convenient for skinning components, has dissapear when select version 4.
Also creating new project appear option between Mxml and 'Mxml+Spark'.

What is this spark?
Do you recommend using this? What are the strong point over tradicional CSS editing?

i am a little bit confused with this.
Br.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark is a new set of components which are identified with their own namespace.
You probably noticed that all components now are prefixed with s: which basically means Spark.
These come default into flex 4.

For example

```
<mx:Application ...>
```

becomes

```
<s:Application ...>
```

I would recommend using it from now on to avoid deprecated coding habits.

Answer (score 0):

spark is an alternative component set. for the most parts, it is more lightweight and it uses FTE and TLF for text rendering, so it can do some nice stuff with text.

when it comes to styling, I don't think spark components differ much from mx components. spark probably is an overall step ahead, but adobe couldn't just drop the older components because a lot of people use them, and because spark relies on Flash Player 10 features.

Comment: Dont you wish they'd come up with some truly lightweight components though? Not an easy task. I think its getting closer though.

Comment: @Tom: personally I wish for a better language. AS3 hasn't had any improvements in the last 3 years. The only progress of the platform is the increasing feature bloat of the player and the framework bloat of flex.

Comment: Yes, they should forget about 'improving' flex so much and concentrate on core stuff.